# Não especificar o caminho até um arquivo em batch

Tags: batch, path

Para abrir um arquivo em meu computador, basta colocar o caminho.
C:\Users\Usuario\Desktop\exemplo\exemplo2.txt
Mas se eu for, por exemplo, criar um batch para um outro computador, supondo que há uma pasta na área de trabalho chamada "exemplo" e um arquivo dentro dela de texto chamado "exemplo2", provavelmente não funcionaria, já que o "Usuario" seria outro nome (no caso, do computador da pessoa), tem alguma forma de contornar isso?

Answer (score 2):

Tenta usar a variável %userprofile% no lugar de user

exemplo:

```
%userprofile%\Desktop
```

Ele vai acessar diretamente o user, independente de qual seja.

Comment: funcionou! muito obrigado